# Missing { inserted. & Missing } inserted

Tags: errors, amsmath

The code works fine and displays the equations I want but it says that I'm missing "{" and "}" in the `\end{align*}` line. And I can not find any solutions to it.

```
\begin{align*}
    x &= \sqrt{5}^\sqrt{2}\\
    &\text{and}\\
    y &= \sqrt{2}\\
    x ^ y &\Rightarrow (\sqrt{5}^\sqrt{2}) ^ \sqrt{2} 
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 6):

You have omitted the needed `{}` around superscripts. `x^\sqrt{2}`  is `x^{\sqrt}{2}` which leads to errors.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    x &= \sqrt{5}^{\sqrt{2}}\\
    &\text{and}\\
    y &= \sqrt{2}\\
    x ^{y} &\Rightarrow (\sqrt{5}^{\sqrt{2}}) ^{\sqrt{2}} 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```